Blue tint after crash entire OS
It looks like my laptop crashed and restarted after open a tab in Chrome (i guess it is RAM excess) and suddenly all the colors look with a blue tinted, how can i fix it? I tried to restart, to be up-to-date but I couldnt make it, Now all the colors change and cannot distinct properly anything...




I don't see a blue tint, so the issue may be specific to your screen. 1. Try changing the color management settings. 2. Try to boot from a live USB to check if the issue persists (then it is a hardware issue)

look the skin of the person... its full blue

The screenshot looks normal on my screen. Most likely, your screen's color management got messed up (hardware issue), or Ubuntu is communicating a wrong color to your screen (some software issue), but it processes the right color internally, which is why your screenshot looks normal to me

really? omg thank you so much, how can I fix it?

Do you see this blue issue in the BIOS/UEFI screen/boot menu?

Also, what is the output of the command echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE?

x11 it is giving, and there is no blue issue in BIOS...

Download brightness controller, and try to change the color ratio with its sliders. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller -y followed by sudo apt update && sudo apt install brightness-controller.

it doesnt work man... sorry
